# Is it impossible to declare methods in an anonymous object?

Tags: javascript

The term anonymous object could be a confusing term so allow me to clarify: by anonymous object I mean the declaration of an object in the same way you would define an anon function.

example:

```
someFunction=function(){}
someObject={}
```

but more specifically anonymous in the way that they can be placed anywhere a variable of such an object or function could be placed. Best (and directly relevant) example being `Object.create`, now like one would use `window.setTimeout(function(){},ms)` (that own function's querks aside) whereas you would just place a function in a variable's stead, I want to be able to do this: `object.Create(some__proto__object,{cake:false})` which is all fine and dandy until I attempt to include methods. Then it throws **TypeError: descriptor must be object.**

So I do some testing in console, I put in `{}` all good, `{cake:"cheesecake",taste:"delicious"}` ok,

```
variable={
   cake:"cheesecake",
   taste:"celicious",
   stateTheCatch:function(){console.log('The cake is a pie!')}
}
```

it works, but

```
//In practical use: 
//Object.create(inheritanceObject,
{
  cake:"cheesecake",
  taste:"celicious",
  stateTheCatch:function(){console.log('The cake is a pie!')}
}//);
```

is broken, and not counted as an object. Why is this bad? Because you type it like that in the second argument for `Object.create` besides using an identifier. So and clues why it doesn't work like that?

Comment: FYI: ECMAScript v3 spec is here, its where javascript comes from: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm, click on '3rd Edition'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are not creating an object at all. When used as a statement, the brackets create a code block, not an object literal.

You can put brackets around any code, but it doesn't do much. (Variables have function scope, so it doesn't even scope variables.)

```
{
  {
    var x = 41;
    {
      {
        x++;
      }
    }
  }
  alert (x);
}
```

If you use the object as a value, it works:

```
function x(y) { y.tateTheCatch(); }

x({
  cake:"cheesecake",
  taste:"celicious",
  tateTheCatch:function(){console.log('The cake is a pie!')}
});
```

In Javascript functions are objects, so you can use a function value anywhere you use another value. It can be sent as parameters, and be stored in variables, object properties and arrays.

Comment: Woah, thanks. Also, like the way you just nonchalantly copied all of my typos.

Comment: Also, apparently surrounding {...} with parenthesis completely fixed it. Thanks for the idea, appreciated.

Comment: @TERMtm: Not so nonchalantly... It's hard to know what's a typo and what's not on any persons native language, so leaving the code mostly unchanged often causes the least confusion. :)